# Given LUP decomposition of a matrix, how to find determinant in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, determinants

I want to compute the determinant of a matrix from its  LUP decomposition in MATLAB. The determinant can be found from the formula:

[image]

P is a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) and  S is the number of exchanges of rows needed to transform P into an identity matrix. How can I find S in the above formula in MATLAB? Does it have any pre-defined functions, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you interpret `P` as an adjacency matrix, and the vector `cycles` contains the length of all cycles in the graph described by `P`, then `S=sum(cycles) - length(cycles)`.

Now all is left is to find the length of all the cycles, for which there are several functions on the File Exchange, like [this one](http://www.mathworks.ch/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29438-count-all-cycles-in-simple-undirected-graph).

BTW: `[L, U, P] = lu(A)`, and `det(A) = det(inv(P))*det(L)*det(U)`

Comment: The function on file exchange does not accept P as an adjacency matrix, because it's not symmetric. What can I do?

Comment: @user215721 `symmetricP = (P+P)'`

Comment: Thank you very much! (a typo in your above comment: symmetricP=P+P')